# how to install apache modules with apt-get

Tags: apache-2.2

Like this titles say, can you install Apache modules with apt-get? or do i have to find the .so file and configure it all manually? I thought i saw that some could, didn't know if that applied to all modules. I'm specifically looking for all the php modules. Right now i'm trying to install mod_fcgid. Any ideas? I'm using Ubuntu Server 12.04, I believe, on an amazon EC2 micro instance running Virtualmin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the command `apt-cache search {search terms}` to find a package name for installation.  In your case you are probably looking for `libapache2-mod-fcgid`.  You can get more details about a package with the command `apt-cache show {packagename}`.

```
$ apt-cache search mod fcgid
libapache2-mod-fcgid - an alternative module compat with mod_fastcgi
libapache2-mod-fcgid-dbg - debugging symbols for mod_fcgid


$ apt-cache search mod php5
...
libapache2-mod-php5 - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (Apache 2 module)
libapache2-mod-php5filter - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (apache 2 filter module)
...
```

Packages that are Apache modules typically have a name that is prefixed with `libapacheN-mod-foo`.

Comment: awesome! that helps so much you can't even imagine!

Comment: In case it is not known yet, also look at what a2enmod and a2dismod (once the packages with the modules themselves have been installed) are for, very comfortable way of managing it..